# EAP application using Eclipse

Tags: ejb-3.0

I have created a sample EJB Project and a Dynamic project.
Now I have used the interface of EJBProject inside the client project so that it could use the proxy object and in turn interact with the bean to fetch the data.

However, I have created a blank EAP project and have added both the EJBProject and the DynamicWebproject. Now according to the concept I have bundled the EJB and Web inside EAp and have deployed on JBoss Server, so technically if I hit the jboss url then it should direct me to welcome page of client. However I am not getting as expected.

Am I doing any mistake in deploying it??

Answer (score 0):

When you will deploy EAP then a target must be generated in that target you will have application.xml in that you will have context root now use this context root in your url foreg: `localhost:yourport/yourprojectname/contextroot`

this must take you to your page

Comment: yes for my project it is: http://localhost:8080/MyEAP  Now what is the contextroot according to you

Comment: In yout project check target file of EAP there will be an application.xml in that you will find the context root...

Comment: no it didnot worked. I am getting the error as expected.

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /MyEAP/EJBCalculatorClient

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /MyEAP/EJBCalculatorClient

description The requested resource (/MyEAP/EJBCalculatorClient) is not available.

Comment: this means the web project is not available there..it is not able to find that... did you added the modules in eap properly  check that